# Printing to logs the "conditon"

Tags: java, android, json, sdk

**NEWEST UPDATE**

```html
package com.karanvir.again;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText city;
    Button go;
    TextView resultofw;
    String text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        city=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        go=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();
        resultofw=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        task.execute("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=76d62bf509e64633a4970055170706&q="+city.toString());


    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//conver result into json object
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);

                //get current JSONObject from result JSONObject
                JSONObject currentJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("current");

                //Now get condition JSONObject from current JSONObject
                JSONObject conditionJSONObject = currentJSONObject.getJSONObject("condition");
                text = conditionJSONObject.getString("text");

                //Now print condition JSONObject
                Log.i("website content", "condition json object : " + text.toString());
                JSONArray arr= new JSONArray(conditionJSONObject.toString());


            } catch (Exception e){

            }

        }
    }

public  void click(View view){

    resultofw.setText(text);
    


}


}
```

SO how can i fix this aswell, im tryng to add the strings to the array. and then pull out what is said after "text"

```html
//conver result into json object
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);

                //get current JSONObject from result JSONObject
                JSONObject currentJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("current");

                //Now get condition JSONObject from current JSONObject
                JSONObject conditionJSONObject = currentJSONObject.getJSONObject("condition");

                //Now print condition JSONObject
                Log.i("website content", "condition json object : " + conditionJSONObject.toString());
                JSONArray arr= new JSONArray(conditionJSONObject.toString());

                for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonpart= arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("Part",jsonpart.getString("text"));
                }
```

**What im trying to do is print everything after ""condition":**{"text":"Partly cloudy","icon":"//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png","code":1003},"wind_mph":15.0,"wind_kph":24.1,"wind_degree":240,"wind_dir":"WSW","pressure_mb":1016.0,"pressure_in":30.5,"precip_mm":0.0,"precip_in":0.0,"humidity":71,"cloud":50,"feelslike_c":9.6,"feelslike_f":49.2,"vis_km":10.0,"vis_miles":6.0}}" **To my logs, im** **using JSONG to process the data from this site**:http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=76d62bf509e64633a4970055170706&q=Paris
**Its not appearing in my logcat, please help** **AND YES I HAVE INCLUDED USES PERMISSION IN MY MENIFEST**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.karanvir.again.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```css
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again E/Zygote: v2
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10291
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G870W_5.0 ver=38
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0013
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.karanvir.again 
06-07 01:42:19.594 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-07 01:42:19.974 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.karanvir.again rsrc of package null
06-07 01:42:20.064 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.304 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.364 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.414 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.484 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.544 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.614 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.694 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.754 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.814 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.894 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.karanvir.again-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
06-07 01:42:20.894 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/lib/arm
06-07 01:42:20.914 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-07 01:42:20.994 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.karanvir.again rsrc of package null
06-07 01:42:20.994 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.karanvir.again-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.karanvir.again rsrc of package null
06-07 01:42:21.114 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-07 01:42:21.424 20523-20780/com.karanvir.again I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-07 01:42:21.424 20523-20780/com.karanvir.again I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-07 01:42:21.464 20523-20787/com.karanvir.again I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ia10634f51b)
                                                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.29.00.00
                                                                Build Date: 01/28/16 Thu
                                                                Local Branch: ss
                                                                Remote Branch: 
                                                                Local Patches: 
                                                                Reconstruct Branch: 
06-07 01:42:21.474 20523-20787/com.karanvir.again I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-07 01:42:21.544 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
06-07 01:42:21.574 20523-20523/com.karanvir.again I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@5600697 time:300881669
```

```html
package com.karanvir.again;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=76d62bf509e64633a4970055170706&q=Paris");


    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//conver result into json object
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);
String xx=jsonObject.getString("condition");
                Log.i("website content", xx);


            } catch (Exception e){

            }

        }
    }




}
```

Comment: try Log.d("website content", jsonObject.getString("condition").toString());

Comment: obviously you should learn some json basics ... condition property is not at root level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `condition` is a `JSONObject` so you need to parse it form result JSONObject as below.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //conver result into json object
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);

            //get current JSONObject from result JSONObject
            JSONObject currentJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("current");

            //Now get condition JSONObject from current JSONObject
            JSONObject conditionJSONObject = currentJSONObject.getJSONObject("condition");

            //Now print condition JSONObject
            Log.i("website content", "condition json object : " + conditionJSONObject.toString());

        } catch (Exception e){

        }

    }
```

**Update:**

Just call `getString` method on `conditionJSONObject` to get value of "text" like below

```
String text = conditionJSONObject.getString("text");
```

Comment: hey thanks your code worked, i had one more part to this question if you dont mind answering sir

Comment: dude your the man, so I got it working finally but it only works for one city. How do I do it so that, it works over and over again everytime I add a new text into it. and that it doesnt just return the citys weather of Victoria. I updated the code bro check er out

Comment: I was thinking of moving the execute code to the on click method?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail or just ask in another question? And give it's link. So I can explain it's solution.

Comment: Ok my problem is that when I run my application so far. What happens is that when I tap my button I only get results for a city, that I entered the first time I ran my app. And then regardless of my trying to enter a new city to find the weather, I get the first city result over and over again.

Comment: thanks man it works can you help me with another one? I dont know why its not working

Comment: Ya sure if I can. Please give me link of your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Log.d("website content", jsonObject.getString("condition").toString());